# Can't type in the AutoCompleteTextView In Android

Tags: android, layout, autocompletetextview

I'm putting a AutoCompleteTextView in my layout, and I can not write anything visible in it! I can not find the solution for this problem.

Here is my Layout:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtOccupation"
        android:layout_width="510dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lblOccupation"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
```

And here is my code to handle the autoCompletion which I write it in the OnCreate():

```
//---AutoComplete ---
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Occupations);
                AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                findViewById(R.id.txtOccupation);
                textView.setThreshold(3);
                textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And I have an array in my activity class:

```
String[] Occupations = {"Software Engineer","Denist","Insustrial Engineer","University Professor","Secretary"};
```

Comment: Your code is correct. What do you mean with "write anything visible"? Is your input invisible?

Comment: I mean I can not see what I'm typing in the textview and no suggestions will appear!

Comment: And you don't got any styles applied to the `AutoCompleteTextView`, altering text color, etc..? Your code works perfectly for me.

Comment: Your posted code works perfectly on my device. There should not be any issue.

Comment: Thanks guys ,I think it's going to work for me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xml put this. in that completionThreshold=1 means, after typind one letter the list displays instead you make it for 2 like that.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
     android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView_search_location"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:completionThreshold="1"
     android:imeOptions="actionDone"
     android:inputType="text"
     android:paddingLeft="10dp"
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:maxLength="20"
     android:textSize="22px" >
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

In Activity it should implements TextWatcher.Then add unimplemented methods for that.And Set the adapter like this.

```
autoCompleteTextView_search_location.addTextChangedListener(this);
autoCompleteTextView_search_location.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,occupations));
```

Let me know your problem is resolved or not.

Comment: but if I want to add a spinner to my layout I should Implement AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener in my layout,how can I merge these two implementation in my code for my activity?is it possible.for example this spinner: <Spinner
  android:id="@+id/spinnerCity"
  android:layout_width="540dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lblBirthCity"
   android:layout_below="@id/rdbGender"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@id/lblLName">
 </Spinner>

Comment: I'm curious. Why add a `TextWatcher` to the `AutoCompleteView`?